# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly'

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

After reading all the existing post related to this issue, i still did not manage to fix it.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly'
```

I have tried all the following:

```
pip3 install plotly
pip3 install plotly --upgrade
```

as well as uninstalling plotly with:

```
pip3 uninstall plotly
```

And reinstalling it again, i get the following on terminal:

```
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from plotly) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: nbformat>=4.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from plotly) (4.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: retrying>=1.3.3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from plotly) (1.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests->plotly) (1.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: idna<2.8,>=2.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests->plotly) (2.7)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests->plotly) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests->plotly) (2018.10.15)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nbformat>=4.2->plotly) (2.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: jupyter-core in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nbformat>=4.2->plotly) (4.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: traitlets>=4.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nbformat>=4.2->plotly) (4.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: ipython-genutils in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nbformat>=4.2->plotly) (0.2.0)

import plotly
import plotly.plotly as py
```

yield:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly'
```

my version of pip(3) as well as python(3) seem to be both fine
May somebody please help?

Using Python3 on Atom 1.32.2 x64

Answer (score 4):

- First of all, Make sure your Python file is NOT called `plotly.py`
  but something else.
- If you are using Anaconda, open Anaconda    Navigator and launch cmd
  prompt (cmd.exe) from there. Then run `pip install plotly` or
  `conda install -c plotly` from that terminal window.
- Or just type `pip install plotly` it will install the package and just restart the kernel hopefully you would be good to go

Comment: I had my filed named plotly.py; that was my issue. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Just run this to uninstall plotly and then build it from source. That should fix the import

```
pip uninstall plotly && python -m pip install plotly
```

Comment: This worked for me! (I was in a rust project, and executing python via `inline-python`)

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a classic dependency issue.

- Check that your pip version is using the same python version (3.6) as what you launch your script with (IE: Use `python3(.6)` to launch your script, not just `python`)
- Your logs aren't showing plotly already installed. In fact, you probably forgot a line when pasting but installing with `pip3.6 install -U plotly` should install the package if not already installed.

Comment: Send the output from pip3 --version and python3 --version

Comment: pip 18.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

Python 3.6.0

Comment: Hum... What about `python3 -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages())"`

Comment: ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/Library/Python/3.6/site-packages']

Comment: That's hella strange. Try `python3 -m pip install -U plotly`?

Comment: Well I'm sorry but I really don't know what to do. Plotly seems to be installed, for the correct version of python, python should be able to see it and you still tell me that `import plotly` doesn't work?

Comment: I used    import plotly.plotly as py before with no problem. Now just tried import plotly but neither of them work

Comment: Are you using (ana)conda? If you have previously installed anaconda this can change the location of the default python3. Try using a venv or conda env to isolte the dependencies you are using

Comment: No i am using atom 1.32

Answer (score 0):

I could with:

```sh
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/plotly plotly
```

Answer (score 0):

I did pip install plotly. It did not work.

Then, I just closed my jupyter-notebook from terminal and opened it again. It worked. Strangely restarting the kernel did not work!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jupyter notebook, try below:

```py
import sys
!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} plotly
```

Comment: Try the above one

Answer (score 0):

best way is to

1-run anaconda navigator
2-go to environment
3- select all
4-and search plotly
5- if not their install it.

[image]
got my issue fixed

Answer (score 0):

*if you are install in Visual Code try:

```
python -m pip3 install plotly
```

or

```
py -m pip3 install plotly
```